# Oracle SQL Select: getting duplicate results joining tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm starting with SQL and doing some exercises and I'm completely stuck on the last one.
It is about looking for streets in the same country name. Two tables are used, locations and countries from the HR schema.
The problem is that I don't know how to avoid duplicate results. For example if I have the street "x" in Canada and the street "y" also in Canada, it shows me twice:

1. street x / Canada / street y
2. street y / Canada / street x
   and I can't find a way to correct this.

My select is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.STREET_ADDRESS AS "CALLE A", C.COUNTRY_NAME, B.STREET_ADDRESS AS "CALLE B"
FROM HR.LOCATIONS A JOIN HR.LOCATIONS B ON (A.STREET_ADDRESS <> B.STREET_ADDRESS), HR.COUNTRIES C
WHERE A.COUNTRY_ID = B.COUNTRY_ID AND B.COUNTRY_ID = C.COUNTRY_ID
ORDER BY C.COUNTRY_NAME
```

I get this Result_

[image: RESULT]

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax _everywhere_. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Where are the duplicates? (From what  I can see each row is different.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use < instead of <>

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.STREET_ADDRESS AS "CALLE A", C.COUNTRY_NAME, B.STREET_ADDRESS AS "CALLE B"
FROM HR.LOCATIONS A JOIN HR.LOCATIONS B ON (A.STREET_ADDRESS > B.STREET_ADDRESS), HR.COUNTRIES C
WHERE A.COUNTRY_ID = B.COUNTRY_ID AND B.COUNTRY_ID = C.COUNTRY_ID
ORDER BY C.COUNTRY_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks!. It's just what I needed, but I still have a little problem.

Up to line 6 is perfect, the results coincide perfectly with the desired output. But from 7 to 13 streets "a" are on "b" and "b" on "a", interchanged.

I get 13 records as I need, the 6 first perfect, from 7 to 13 exchanged.

Comment: that is a new question, so accept here an answer and ask a new one. and add a ]mre} to your question so that people anderstand whaz is actually in 7 till 13 . you can program the order also of if iot is always the half add a row_number

Comment: OK, give me some hours. Whe I start the new question, I´ll put photo from the required output.

Comment: Warning, you shouldn't use photos / images.  Just provide the actual `INSERT` statements.  Remember, it's the same question if you still see reflections.  Something is wrong in your review or your description.  This solution can't generate those reflections.

Comment: New question in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69620302/oracle-sql-doesnt-show-me-the-desired-order-columns-swapped

Answer (score 0):

All the correct answers should be logically equivalent.  You may want to use a form closer to this, however.

Ignore the alignment, unless you feel it helps readability (I happen to).

I'm referring more to the JOIN / ON form (avoid comma separated table expressions in the `FROM` clause, called `<table reference list>` ... a single `<table reference>` is usually sufficient), as @jarlh mentioned, and to keep the join criteria (in the `ON` clauses) nearer to the corresponding tables in the `FROM` clause, unless you have a particular reason to separate any of the logic to the `WHERE` clause (try to avoid that, unless necessary).

Logically, we can write these in lots of different ways.  Some may be a little easier to write/read.

```
SELECT A.STREET_ADDRESS AS "CALLE A"
     , C.COUNTRY_NAME
     , B.STREET_ADDRESS AS "CALLE B"
  FROM HR.LOCATIONS A
  JOIN HR.LOCATIONS B
    ON A.COUNTRY_ID     = B.COUNTRY_ID
   AND A.STREET_ADDRESS < B.STREET_ADDRESS
  JOIN HR.COUNTRIES C
    ON B.COUNTRY_ID     = C.COUNTRY_ID
 ORDER BY C.COUNTRY_NAME
;
```

The inequality, as @nbk points out, avoids the street reflections.

`SELECT DISTINCT` isn't really needed for this, if your join logic and selected detail is sufficient to identify unique locations.  If not, the result probably isn't practically useful.

If this is a small subset of sample data and/or these street addresses are unique within each country, then you're also ok, and `DISTINCT` isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks. I get exactly the same output as with NBK, and I have the same problem from line 7 to 13, as I have commented in the answer to NBK.

Comment: I'm not sure you tried these answers precisely.  You can't get the result in (both) 7 and 8 if you follow the above exactly.  Try providing a complete test case so that we all can execute and see the result.  I realize my answer is logically equivalent to @nbk ...  I added more detail in the answer since you mentioned you were new to SQL.  Lots of these concepts could be missing from your understanding.